# How to add followers from two one2many field in a custom module?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have two One2many fields of different classes and would like to know how to add the users/partners as followers of the document(Add followers while saving or on click of a button).

I have been trying the following:

```
mail_follower_ids = []
        if sobj.matp:  # matp is a one2many field
            for ma in sobj.matp:
                partner_ids = partner_pool.search(cr, uid, [('name','=',ma.empname.name), ('email','=',ma.wk_mail)])
                if partner_ids:
                    for partner in partner_ids:
                        mail_follower_ids.append(partner)

        if sobj.newa:
            for new in sobj.newa:  # newa is a one2many field
                partner_ids = partner_pool.search(cr, uid, [('name','=',new.empname.name), ('email','=',new.wk_mail)])
                if partner_ids:
                    for partner in partner_ids:
                        mail_follower_ids.append(partner)
```

but could not go on further, anyone with any suggestion will be really grateful. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If your model inherits email.thread or you're inheriting a model which already is inheriting email.thread you can use message_subscribe on your model to add partners.

Definition:

```py
def message_subscribe(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_ids, subtype_ids=None, context=None):
    """ Add partners to the records followers. """
```

Just look into mail.mail_thread to find some useful methods :-)